# My program breaks at 3rd cycle of initialization of array of char*. Cannot understand why it happens. Explain, please

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

If I try to run program and ititialize only 2 strings (char*), it works OK. But when I try 3, 4 and more strings initialize, then program just stops. What do I miss?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template <typename T>
T maxn(T*, int);
template <> char* maxn(char**, int);
template <typename T>
void fill_array(T*, int);

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    int N;
    cout << "Input size of array of integers: ";
    cin >> N;
    int *Arr = new int[N];
    fill_array(Arr, N);
    cout << "\nMax number in your array is " << maxn(Arr, N) << '\n';
    delete [] Arr;
    cout << "Input size of array of doubles: ";
    cin >> N;
    double *ArrDouble = new double[N];
    fill_array(ArrDouble, N);
    cout << "\nMax number in your array is " << maxn(ArrDouble, N) << '\n';
    delete [] ArrDouble;
    cout << "Input number of strings, that you plan to input: ";
    cin >> N;
    cin.get();
    char **ArrChar = new char*[N];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        cout << "Input string #" << i+1 << ": ";
        cin.getline(ArrChar[i], 40);
    }
    cout << "The longest string starts at " << reinterpret_cast<void*>(maxn(ArrChar, N)) << " address";
    delete [] ArrChar;
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
void fill_array(T* p_T, int N)
{
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a number #" << i+1 << ": ";
        std::cin >> p_T[i];
    }
    std::cout << "Array was initializated. Well done!\n";
    return;
}

template <typename T>
T maxn(T* p_T, int N)
{
    T max=p_T[0];
    for (int i=0; i<N-1; i++)
    {
        if (p_T[i]<p_T[i+1]) max=p_T[i+1]; 
    }
    return max;
}

template <> char* maxn(char** str, int N)
{
    char* max_len=&str[0][0];
    for (int i=0; i<N-1; i++)
    {
        if (strlen(str[i])<strlen(str[i+1])) max_len=&str[i+1][0];
    }
    return max_len;
}
```

I suppose, that problem chains with allocate memory, but don't sure. I tried it with fixwd-size array - program breaks after input first string...

Comment: Why are you not using `std::string` and `std::vector`?

Comment: It crashes because you are using uninitialised pointers.

Comment: [Useful tool](https://godbolt.org/z/nKrvTK7eb).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I try to understand, how it works. Thats why I don't use `std::string` and `std::vector` in this training program.

Comment: The reason why I asked is that you are using templates.  It then makes sense to ask as to why you're using a feature of C++ such as templates, and not use components of C++ such as `std::vector` and `std::string`, which have been officially part of C++ for 24 years now.

Comment: Avoid using `new` and `delete`, they are usually unnecessary in modern C++. You will benefit more and learn more by reading up on and using `std::make_unique`, `std::make_shared`, `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc. etc. instead.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, that one of tasks in C++ by Steven Prata. Just doing them all)

Comment: *Steven Prata* -- Never heard of him.  But I've heard of Bjarne Stroustrup, and here is what [he says about learning C++ the way you are learning it](https://www.stroustrup.com/new_learning.pdf)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, these really nice tools for programming real software. But now I want to dive deeper and try something old-fashioned, but principal.

Comment: C++ Primer Plus wasn't one of the better C++ programming texts when I had cause to look at it. May have improved in later revisions, though. I haven't been keeping up.

Comment: @user4581301, C++ Primer Plus on the way to me from shop) As Bjarne Stroustrup's "Principles and practice using c++".

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
char **ArrChar = new char*[N];
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    cout << "Input string #" << i+1 << ": ";
    cin.getline(ArrChar[i], 40);
}
```

to this

```
char **ArrChar = new char*[N];
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    ArrChar[i] = new char[40]; // <-- ADD THIS!
    cout << "Input string #" << i+1 << ": ";
    cin.getline(ArrChar[i], 40);
}
```

You need to allocate some memory for your strings, `getline` won't do that for you.

Comment: Don't forget that with this approach, you have to `delete[]` each individual `char*` string in `ArrChar` before then `delete[]`'ing `ArrChar` itself. This wouldn't have been a problem if `std::string` had been used instead of `char*`.